# Why is a new axis created, when only the first element is needed?

Tags: tensorflow, image-segmentation, argmax

*First of all, sorry for the vague title*

As I was interested in learning more about TensorFlow and Image segmentation, I was following their tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/segmentation). However, I noticed something that I could not quite grasp, also not after some Googling around.

In this section:

```
def create_mask(pred_mask):
    pred_mask = tf.argmax(pred_mask, axis=-1)
    pred_mask = pred_mask[..., tf.newaxis]
    return pred_mask[0]
```

What is the reason for first creating a new axis to the pred_mask vector, only right after that to pick only the first element? Why is not like I expected, as seen below:

```
def create_mask(pred_mask):
    pred_mask = tf.argmax(pred_mask, axis=-1)
    return pred_mask
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `tf.argmax` on with `axis=-1` make the tensor loose the last channel. This is added back as a singleton channel via `tf.newaxis`.

Then you return the first element of the batch. In short:

```py
(batch_size, height, width, channels)  # original tensor shape
(batch_size, height, width)            # after argmax
(batch_size, height, width, 1)         # after unsqueeze
(height, width, 1)                     # this is what you are returning
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just to keep images being 3D tensors. For example, if you have predictions with shape `(1, 256, 256, 10)` (batch of one 256x256 image 10 classes), after `tf.argmax()` you'll receive a tensor with shape `(1, 256, 256)` (batch of one 256x256 image without channels). But usually, it's easier to work with images if they are in HWC format `(Height, Width, Channel)` instead of just `(Height, Width)`. For example, if you use matplotlib or OpenCV, you usually need HWC images.

Answer (score 0):

in image segmentation, the input to the U-Net architecture  is (samples, H, W, channels) and you get the output as (samples, H, W, n-classes)
--(sample is the batch of images )--  let's take one image of this sample it will be (1, H, W,n_classes) this means each pixel of the image can belong to n-classes with different probability so we want to know each pixel highest class probability so we set this pixel to a specific class. using **argmax(axis=-1)** will give you a mask of True and false values of (1, H, W), the n-classes are dropped, we have selected the pixel but dropped its class, using this mask you will not be able to select from the (1, H, W,n-classes), we just want to add back more dimensional to the end of the (1, H, W) mask that we have.
with the help of **pred_mask[..., tf.newaxis]** or **tf.expand_dims(a,axis=1)**
we can constract the mask to be
(1,H,W,TheHeighestprobablityclass)

```
np.random.seed(2)
pixel=np.random.random((1,2,2,3)) #
pixel[0,0,1,:] #pixel(1,1) #with three classes probability  it should belong to class 0
```

output

```
array([0.43532239, 0.4203678 , 0.33033482]) #0 is heighest
```

Check Pixel  which is ( 2x2 image ) each pixel has 3 classes

```
pixel
```

output

```
array([[[[0.4359949 , 0.02592623, 0.54966248],
         [0.43532239, 0.4203678 , 0.33033482]],

        [[0.20464863, 0.61927097, 0.29965467],
         [0.26682728, 0.62113383, 0.52914209]]]])
```

shape (1, 2, 2, 3)

The Mask

```
mask=pixel.argmax(-1)
mask #you can't select from above with this mask cuz of it's shape add more dim to match the image
```

output

```
     array([[[2, 0],
                [1, 1]]], dtype=int64)
```

mask.shape (1, 2, 2)

Go

```
mask=mask[..., np.newaxis] #pixel (0,1) mask say 0 which is What we expect
mask.shape
mask.shape #now we can use this mask to select max class  from each pixel of  our 2x2 image
```

output

```
   array([[[[2],
             [0]],
    
            [[1],
             [1]]]], dtype=int64)
```

shape (1, 2, 2, 1)
**Now you can use the mask with the image that's why he add more dim.**